# How to implement a trait with 'static lifetime for a struct with lifetime 'a?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have a `trait Surface: 'static` that I want to implement for a `struct Obj<'a>`. The trait needs to be `'static` because I want to store objects from type `Surface` in a `Vec<Box<Surface>>`.

In the first step I tried this.

```
impl<'a> Surface for Obj<'a> {}
```

This will not work because of a lifetime mismatch between `'static` and `'a`. In other words: `Surface` can live longer than `Obj` because `Surface` is `'static`.
I changed my implementation as follows.

```
impl<'a> Surface for Obj<'a> where 'a: 'static {}
```

As far as I understand the documentation correctly, what I'm doing is, `'a` can outlive `'static`. Do I want this?

If I transfer the ownership of `Obj<'a>`, the compiler tells me that a mutable reference inside `Obj` will not live long enough and is still borrowed.

Here is a short example.

```
trait Surface: 'static {}

struct Manager {
    storage: Vec<Box<Surface>>,
}

impl Manager {
    fn add(&mut self, surface: impl Surface) {
        self.storage.push(Box::new(surface));
    }
}

struct SomeOtherStruct {}

struct Obj<'a> {
    data: &'a mut SomeOtherStruct,
}

impl<'a> Obj<'a> {
    fn new(some_struct: &'a mut SomeOtherStruct) -> Self {
        Obj { data: some_struct }
    }
}

impl<'a> Surface for Obj<'a> where 'a: 'static {}

fn main() {
    let mut some_struct = SomeOtherStruct {};
    let mut manager = Manager {
        storage: Vec::new(),
    };

    let obj = Obj::new(&mut some_struct);
    manager.add(obj);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=114c32349d4b9893f810c6bfe3297bd8))

```
error[E0597]: `some_struct` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:33:24
   |
33 |     let obj = Obj::new(&mut some_struct);
   |               ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |               |        |
   |               |        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |               argument requires that `some_struct` is borrowed for `'static`
34 |     manager.add(obj);
35 | }
   | - `some_struct` dropped here while still borrowed
```

In other words `&mut some_struct` is lifetime `'a` but needs `'static`. Ok it's clear because `some_struct` lives in `Obj<'a>` so it cannot be `'static`?

Is this what I'm trying to do "Rust like"? I've no idea how to get it to work. Its really confusing with the lifetimes. I think I can get around this by using a `Rc<T>`, but this will make things more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to implement a trait with `'static` lifetime for a struct with lifetime `'a`?

You do not and cannot. The purpose of the `'static` lifetime is to say "something that lives for the entire duration of the program". No arbitrary lifetime `'a` meets this requirement *except* `'static` itself.

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

```
impl<'a> Surface for Obj<'a> where 'a: 'static {}
```

is verbose for

```
impl Surface for Obj<'static> {}
```

---

You identified your problem correctly:

> In other words `&mut some_struct` is lifetime `'a` but needs `'static`

You need to declare `some_struct` as `static`:

```
fn main() {
    static mut SOME_STRUCT: SomeOtherStruct = SomeOtherStruct {};
    // ...
    let obj = unsafe { Obj::new(&mut SOME_STRUCT) };
    //  ...
}
```

The problem is, that you cannot access mutable static variables safely, because they can be mutated be multiple thread simultaneously and that is a problem, hence you need `unsafe`.

So no, your code is not "Rust like", but I'm afraid you can't change that with your current architecture.

---

> The trait needs to be 'static because I want to store objects from type `Surface` in a `Vec<Box<Surface>>`.

I don't get why you think you need `'static` in the first place, e.g. this code is perfectly legal:

```
trait Foo {}
struct Bar;

impl Foo for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let b: Box<Foo> = Box::new(Bar);
}
```

Comment: Ok... first thanks for your answer. That is not what I want. I want the "rust way". Can you show me the rust way, or give me a hint that can I figure it out alone. I made my trait `'static`, because of a compiler error on this signature `fn add(&mut self, surface: impl Surface)` without `'static` the compiler will throw an error, but thanks for the hint I changed it as follows: `fn add(&mut self, surface: impl Surface + 'static)`. Now I can remove the 'static from the trait. But the problem still exists. If I have to refactor my architecture, to archive the rust way, no problem, I'm learning.

Answer (score 3):

[@hellow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55157361/155423) works and solves my problem, but it feels hacky and working against Rust.

With your hints, I found a better solution that alsos work and does not use `unsafe`.

**Solution 1**

I specified explicit lifetime parameters for the `Manager` and for the type `Box<Surface + 'a>`:

```
trait Surface {}

struct Manager<'a> {
    storage: Vec<Box<Surface + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Manager<'a> {
    fn add(&mut self, surface: impl Surface + 'a) {
        self.storage.push(Box::new(surface));
    }
}

struct SomeOtherStruct {}

struct Obj<'a> {
    data: &'a mut SomeOtherStruct,
}

impl<'a> Obj<'a> {
    fn new(some_struct: &'a mut SomeOtherStruct) -> Self {
        Obj {
            data: some_struct
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Surface for Obj<'a> {}

fn main() {
    let mut some_struct = SomeOtherStruct{};
    let mut manager = Manager { storage: Vec::new() };

    let obj = Obj::new(&mut some_struct);
    manager.add(obj);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa3aca0c435797da1630d3ff5b2ada49))

**Solution 2**

Store a `Box<SomeOtherStruct>` instead of `&mut SomeOtherStruct` in `Obj`. This will eliminate the lifetimes:

```
trait Surface {}

struct Manager {
    storage: Vec<Box<Surface>>,
}

impl Manager {
    fn add(&mut self, surface: impl Surface + 'static) {
        self.storage.push(Box::new(surface));
    }
}

struct SomeOtherStruct {}

struct Obj {
    data: Box<SomeOtherStruct>,
}

impl Obj {
    fn new(some_struct: Box<SomeOtherStruct>) -> Self {
        Obj {
            data: some_struct
        }
    }
}

impl Surface for Obj {}

fn main() {
    let some_struct = SomeOtherStruct{};
    let mut manager = Manager { storage: Vec::new() };

    let obj = Obj::new(Box::new(some_struct));
    manager.add(obj);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18954cd6563a6b2bfc226006e0c7f07f))

In my opinion both solutions are good. I don't know which solution is better and I've no experience with pro and cons of this solutions.
For me (maybe because I'm a beginner and still leaning Rust) it's easier to avoid lifetimes and use `Box`, `Rc` etc.